# Django Filter Backend not working in restful api in django

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to use django-filters in have search queries in url using params

view.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from .models import RecruiterRegister
from .serializers import RecruiterRegisterSerializer
# from rest_framework import filters

from rest_framework import generics

class RecruiterRegisterList(APIView):

    queryset=RecruiterRegister.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter ,)
    filter_fields = ('email','password')
    search_fields = ('email','password')
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        recruiterRegisters = RecruiterRegister.objects.all()
        # self.filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
        # self.filter_fields = ('password', )
        serializer = RecruiterRegisterSerializer(recruiterRegisters, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = RecruiterRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        recruiterRegisters = self.get_object()
        recruiterRegisters.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

but I am not able to get filtered data. All the api data appears.

url sample
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/recruiterRegister/?password=random2

edited RecruiterRegisterList class:

```
class RecruiterRegisterList(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset=RecruiterRegister.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecruiterRegisterSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields=('email','password')
    # search_fields = ('email','password')

    def list(self, request ):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = RecruiterRegisterSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to filter users by password?

Comment: dont want to filter using password, was trying for any field @Ken4scholars

Comment: Like I mentioned, you don't need to override the list method unless you want to customize it. The `filter_queryset` method is called inside the list method which you're not doing. If you really want to override it anyway, check how the original list method is implemented and use the same logic. You're omitting many things like pagination, filtering etc.

Comment: For a start just remove that list method and see that it works. You can then override and customize later if you really need to

Comment: get request is working without list method but filter isn't

Comment: what exactly do you mean by not working? post an example request and result

Comment: Let me repeat again that filtering by password will not work because only the hash is stored in the DB and not the password itself

Answer (score 2):

First question is - why would you ever want to filter or search by password? that is a very unhealthy and unsecure design. Passwords are not stored in their raw formats but hashed so the filters will never hit anyway

Now, even if you really wanted to do that, filtering using `filter_backends` is implemented in the `GenericAPIView` and not available in `APIView` so you may want to use the `ListAPIview` from `rest_framework.generics` instead.

Lastly, even if you used the `ListAPIView`, it still wouldn't work because you're overriding the `get` method and not calling `self.filter_queryset()`.

Use the `ListAPIView` and use the already implemented `list()` method and it will work

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding only the line bellow & working fine:

```
filter_backends = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
```

And your code like:

```
class RecruiterRegisterList(generics.ListAPIView):

queryset=RecruiterRegister.objects.all()
serializer_class = RecruiterRegisterSerializer
filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
filter_fields=('email','password')
search_fields = ('email','password')

def list(self, request ):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    filter_backends = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
    serializer = RecruiterRegisterSerializer(filter_backends, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```